# Table: Adjust width of cells

Tags: tables, exam

I want to create the layout shown below which appears at the top of a math test.

[image]

The code currently renders as shown below.

[image]

The cells with "Name" and "Period" need to be further right. I tried to use `\hline` to create a blank fill-in line for those 2 cells, but that causes multiple errors.

Thank you for taking time to read and respond to my post!

````
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\pagestyle{head}
{}
{} 
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
 }
\begin{table}[!htp]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{Algebra II: Q3 Final Exam - Part 1} & Name:\hline \\
\textbf{(Units 8 \& 9)} & Period:\hline \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\newlength{\lwidth}
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} 
\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, 
    item-indent=0pt,  
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},
    column-sep=2em,    
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate,start=2](1)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf
{Simplify each expression to a single value without using a calculator. \emph{Show work.}\\(NO calculators)}}
%%% Prob #44
\task 
In 2015, there were 75 wolves in Yellowstone National Park. Due to the efforts of park officials, 
the population grew to 90 wolves in 2016. This trend continues and the wolf population increases exponentially.
\begin{solutionorbox}
$answer here$
\end{solutionorbox}
\bigskip

\end{tasks}
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest setting the heading of the fist page using the optional arguments of `\lhead` and `\rhead`

```
\rhead[<on the first page>]{<on the other pages>}
```

That way, you'll use the header space for exam  titles.

The command
`\extraheadheight[0.7cm]{0cm}`
gives 0.7cm of additional head height on the first page while maintaining the original
height on all pages after the first.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}% changed
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}

% *********************************** first page header added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pagestyle{head}
\lhead[\bfseries Algebra II: Q3 Final Exam - Part 1\\ (Units 8 \& 9)]{}
\rhead[{\parbox[b]{0.5\linewidth}{Name:\enspace\hrulefill \\%
        Period:\enspace\hrulefill\enspace(65 points total for Parts 1 \& 2)}}]{}
\extraheadheight[0.7cm]{0cm}
%    ***********************************

\printanswers %<<<<
\begin{document}

    \newlength{\lwidth}
    \settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} 
    \settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
        after-skip=2cm,
        label-width=\lwidth, 
        item-indent=0pt,  
        label=(\arabic*), % 
        label-offset = -\lwidth,
        item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},
        column-sep=2em,    
    }
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
        \vbox{%     
            \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
            \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
            \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
            #1}%
        \nobreak
    }
    \makeatother
    \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
    \begin{tasks}
        [style=enumerate,start=2](1)
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf
            {Simplify each expression to a single value without using a calculator. \emph{Show work.}\\(NO calculators)}}
        %%% Prob #44
        \task 
        In 2015, there were 75 wolves in Yellowstone National Park. Due to the efforts of park officials, 
        the population grew to 90 wolves in 2016. This trend continues and the wolf population increases exponentially.
        \begin{solutionorbox}
        \emph{answer here}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \bigskip
        
    \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Use this code to add vertical space between *Name* and *Period*

```
% *********************************** first page header added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pagestyle{head}
\lhead[{\parbox[b]{0.50\linewidth}{\raggedright \bfseries Algebra II: Q3 Final Exam - Part 1\\[\baselineskip] (Units 8 \& 9)}}]{}
\rhead[{\parbox[b]{0.50\linewidth}{Name:\enspace\enspace\hrulefill \\[\baselineskip]%
        Period:\enspace\hrulefill\enspace(65 points total for Parts 1 \& 2)}}]{}
\extraheadheight[0.7cm]{0cm}
%    ***********************************
```

[image: e]